# How to create CDATA content from multiple nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML looks like this

```
<Root>
<id>123</id>
<title>Inetgrate item</title>
<note><![CDATA[test entry]]></note>
<feedback><![CDATA[test entry]]></feedback>
<description><![CDATA[description of the records]]></description>
<owner>ABC</owner>
<integration_notes><![CDATA[steps for integration]]></integration_notes>
</Root>
```

I want the output to be like this

```
<Task>
<id>123</id>
<Summary>Inetgrate item</Summary>
<comments>
<![CDATA[note: test entry
feedback: test entry
integration_notes: steps for integration
]]></comments>
<description><![CDATA[description of the records]]></description>
<owner>ABC</owner>
</Task>
```

CDATA in the "Comments" node in the output is the concatenation of 3 other nodes.

I am trying to achieve this in XSLT (1.0)

Is it possible to somehow do this via XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="comments description"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Root">
  <Task>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </Task>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="note">
  <comments>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=". | ../feedback | ../integration_notes" mode="m1"/>
  </comments>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="feedback | integration_notes"/>

<xsl:template match="note | feedback | integration_notes" mode="m1">
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1"><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(), ': ', .)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

An XSLT stylesheet doesn't know (or care) whether the text in its input XML document was represented as CDATA or not - the parser handles that and the stylesheet just sees the unwrapped content.  So it sees

```
<note><![CDATA[test entry]]></note>
```

and

```
<note>test entry</note>
```

as equivalent.  Similarly, in the output side you just create text nodes and it's up to the serializer whether to encode them as CDATA sections or just to escape all the `<` and `&` characters as required.  You can't force one particular text node to be output as CDATA but you can request that *all* elements with a given name be output as CDATA using

```
<xsl:output method="xml" cdata-section-elements="comments description" />
```

at the top level of your stylesheet.